# use curl in php nitrous

Tags: php, curl, io, nitrousio

I'm developing a project that uses CURL PHP, but I'm not being able to install the curl extension since I've not the root user of the "Nitrous.io" box.

There is another alternative to install CURL PHP in a Nitrous.io PHP Box?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what do you want to achieve with CURL ? may be there are other ways to do that, with out involving CURL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just re-install php5 package on nitrous.io box

```
$ parts update
$ parts install php5
$ php -m | grep curl
curl 
$ php -r 'echo curl_version()["version"] . PHP_EOL;'
7.22.0
```

Comment: After running `parts install php5`, you may also need to restart Apache2. `parts stop apache2` , `parts start apache2`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Nitrious.io, but if you are unable to access/install curl for your project, you will have to contact Nitrious directly about using curl.

Also, you might be able to use [fsocketopen](https://www.php.net/fsockopen) to solve your issue.  Example:

```
$fp = fsockopen("www.example.com", 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)
\n";
} else {
    $out = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $out .= "Host: www.example.com\r\n";
    $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
    fwrite($fp, $out);
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        echo fgets($fp, 128);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
```